# Recursões em closures

Tags: python, recursão, closures, decorator-pattern

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def memoize(limit, *, message = 'Limit exceded'):
    count = 0
    def inner(func):
        cache = {}
        def wrapped(number):
            nonlocal count
            if count < limit:
                if number not in cache:
                    cache[number] = func(number)
                count += 1
                return cache[number]
            print(message)
        return wrapped
    return inner

@memoize(5)
def fat(x):
    if x < 2:
        return 1
    return x * fat(x - 1)
```

---

Em teoria o algoritmo deveria receber um número que definiria um limite de armazenamento dos resultados num cache, ao invés de levantar uma exceção eu simplesmente mostra a mensagem que foi passada ou a padrão ("Limit exceded") caso o número limite no cache seja atingido.
O problema é que ele só executa o programa uma única vez e mostra a mensagem, mas onde está o erro ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código está certinho (com o único detalhe que não faz sentido manter a variável `count` sozinha em `memoize` - ela deveria ou estar dentro do `inner`, ou o `cache` deveria estar fora, junto com ela, mas isso é quese estético).

O que acontece é que *a sua funçao decorada é ela mesma recursiva*, ou seja, uma única chamada a `fat` vai chamar o wrapper do decorador n vezes: daí já estoura seu limite de 5 chamadas. Aumente o limite de chamadas, ou faça a chamada para fat com um número menor e vai ver que é isso.

Se desejar que as chamadas re-entrantes à fat não contem para o limite, você pode colocar um contador para detectar recursão, e não aumentar o `count` interno nesse caso (e aí, cuidado que a coisa começa a complicar se o programa for multi-thread, esse contador de recursão tem que ser uma variável thread-local)

```
def memoize(limit, *, message = 'Limit exceded'):
    def inner(func):
        count = 0
        cache = {}
        recursing = 0
        def wrapped(number):
            nonlocal count, recursing

            if count < limit:
                recursing += 1
                if number not in cache:
                    cache[number] = func(number)
                recursing -= 1
                if not recursing:
                    count += 1
                return cache[number]
            print(message)
        return wrapped
    return inner
```

Comment: Pelo que entendi no seu código você está se aproveitando do fato de saber que está havendo uma recursão no código e incrementando e decrementando a variável recursing a cada passagem da recursão ???

Comment: O código não está "se aproveitando" de nada - ele _fica sabendo_ que está numa recursão por que essa variável é incrementada/decrementada